# Adding weight and volume to woocommerce products

Tags: wordpress, e-commerce, woocommerce, fedex, woothemes

I'm trying to configure the FedEx plugin on my woocommerce installation. According to the woocommerce documentation: http://wcdocs.woothemes.com/user-guide/extensions/shipping-methods/fedex/

> The FedEx Shipping Extension only works when your products have a defined volume and weight. That’s how it calculates what to charge for shipping. Whenever you add a new product to your inventory, make sure you have entered its weight along with the size of the smallest box you plan to ship it in.

The problem is when I'm adding a new product or editing an existing one, I do not see these options anywhere.

This is what the documentation shows

[image: This is what the documentation shows]

This is what I see

[image: This is what I see]

The shipping tab isn't much help either - it just has a shipping class dropdown menu. Tried creating a test shipping class, but I don't see anywhere where to specify weight and/or volume. Any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Those fields will only display on the edit product page if you enable them.

Go to WooCommerce -> Settings and click on the "Catalog" tab.  Then under the "Product Data" section check the boxes next to "Enable the weight field for products" and "Enable the dimension fields for products".